# Create Inverse of an vector function

Tags: inverse-function

I have a function which maps a vector to a scalar.

$$ f(q, r) = 135 + q + \frac {r( 39 - |r| )}{2} $$

The domain for q is: $$ q \in \mathbb{Z}, -9 <= q <= 9  $$

The domain for r is: $$ r \in \mathbb{Z}, -9 <= r <= 9  $$

The range of this function (u) is : $$ u \in \mathbb{N}, 0 <= u <= 270  $$

I want to create the function

$$f^{-1}(x,y) $$

But I am unable to.

I've tried breaking the problem into pieces to get try to get a better handle on it:

but I can't solve the simpler problem of inversing mapping the r component of the vector either.

$$ f(x) = 135 + \frac {x( 39 - |x| )}{2} $$

To create the function inverse function

$$ f^{-1}(x) $$

My first thought was the f(x) could be a quadratic (and I could create the inverse function by completing the square) but after graphing it is nothing like a quadratic.

[image: graph]

Comment: I am a bit lost. What exactly is your issue ?

Comment: I want to find the inverse function of f(x,y)